# How to determine the inflection point of non-equilibrium solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
\dfrac{dP}{dt} = 0.2P\left(1-\dfrac{P}{1000}\right)
$$
I am asked to find out the common inflection point of each non-equilibrium solution. How to do that? (I know the equilibrium points are $P = 0$, and $P = 1000$)

Answer (score 1):

The second derivative is
$$
\frac{d^2P}{dt^2}=0.2\left(1-2\frac{P}{1000}\right)\,\frac{dP}{dt}
$$
which you can now easily set to zero.

Answer (score 0):

set coefficient to 1 and consider

$$P^{'}= P(a-P)$$

Maximum  of $P'$ occurs (inflection occurs) when $P^{''}= 0$ at $P=a/2$ i.e., at $ P=a/2=1000/2. $